# Graham Scan for calculating the convex hull of a given set of points in R

Tags: r, algorithm, convex-hull

I need to code the Graham scan algorithm to find convex hull of a given set of points. I have been trying a lot and, I do not achieve a solution.

I have the following code for graham function

EDIT : add comments to help understand code flow

```
grahamScanConvexHull<-function(points){
  # Points is a dataset with eeach row a point one column x and one column
  # (We can assume that there are not three points collinear)

  # Vertices is a simulated stack were the solution is stored
  vertices <- data.frame(x=double(), y=double())

  flag <- T # Flag used in case there two points with the least y

  # Get the most left down_point and leave others in points
  points  <- quicksort_bottom_top(points, 1, nrow(points))

  # if there are two points with the same lowest y we get the leftmost 
  if(points[1,]$y == points[2,]$y){ 
    if(points[1,]$x < points[2,]$x){
      point_0 <- points[1,]
      points <- points[(2:nrow(points)),]
    }else{
      point_0 <- points[2,]
      points <- points[c(1, 3:nrow(points)),]
    }
  }else{
    point_0 <- points[1,]
    points <- points[(2:nrow(points)),]
    flag  <- F
  }

  # Sort the points related to de most left point
  points <- quicksort_angle(points, 1, nrow(points), point_0)
  # This is used in case that there are two points with the lowest y be put first   
  # in the list of points (it will we the last in other case)
  if(flag){
    first_point <- points[nrow(points),]
    points <- rbind(first_point, points[(1:(nrow(points)-1)),])
  }

  # Push the point with the lowest y (ledtmost) and the point with lest polar 
  #angle
  vertices <- push(vertices, point_0)
  vertices <- push(vertices, points[1,])

  for(i in 1:nrow(points)){
    # Get the top 2 points in the stack as vectors
    next_to_top <- c(next_to_top(vertices)$x,next_to_top(vertices)$y)
    top <- c(top(vertices)$x,top(vertices)$y)

    # Get the oncheck point as a vector
    point_i <- c(points[i,]$x,points[i,]$y)

    while(nrow(vertices) >= 2 & (rightTurn(next_to_top, top, point_i) <= 0)){
      vertices <- pop(vertices)

      # Recalculate the top two points of the stack (as vector) after pop 
      next_to_top <- next_to_top(vertices)
      next_to_top <- c(next_to_top$x, next_to_top$y)

      top <- top(vertices)
      top <- c(top$x, top$y)

    }
    # Push the onCheck point into the stack
    vertices <- push(vertices, points[i,])
  }

  return(vertices)
}
```

For managing the stack I have code this short auxiliary function

```
top <- function(stack){
  return(stack[1,])
} 
next_to_top <- function(stack){
  return(stack[2,])
} 
pop <- function(stack){
  return(stack[-1,])
}
push <- function(stack, e){
  if(e$x %in% stack$x & e$y %in% stack$y ){
    if(which(e$x %in% stack$x) == which(e$y %in% stack$y)){
      return(stack)
    }else{
      stack <- rbind(e, stack)
      return(stack)
    }
  }else{
    stack <- rbind(e, stack)
    return(stack)
  }
}
```

And for counter clockwise I have the following function:

```
rightTurn <- function(A, B,  C) {
  val <- (B[1] - A[1]) * (C[2] - A[2]) -
    (B[2] - A[2]) * (C[1] - A[1])
  return(val)
}
```

The sorting functions I have checked many times and, I am plenty sure they are fine (also I have been using them for a long time without any problem).
I do not know what I am doing wrong so any help is welcomed.

EDIT:

Code of quicksort_bottom_top()

```
quicksort_bottom_top <- function(points, low, high) {
  if (low < high) {
    list_particion <- partition_bottom_top(points, low, high)
    p <- list_particion[['p']]
    points <- list_particion[['points']]
    points <- quicksort_bottom_top(points, low, p - 1)
    points <- quicksort_bottom_top(points, p + 1, high)
  }
  return(points)
}

partition_bottom_top <- function(points, low, high) {
  pivot <- points[high, ]
  i <- low
  for (j in low:high) {
    if (points[j, ]$y < pivot$y) {
      points <- swap(points, i, j)
      i <- i + 1
    }
  }
  points <- swap(points, i, high)
  return(list('points' = points, 'p' = i))
}
```

Code of quicksort_angle()

```
quicksort_angle<-function(points, low, high, reference_point){
  if (low < high) {
    list_particion <- partition_angle(points, low, high, reference_point)
    p <- list_particion[['p']]
    points <- list_particion[['points']]
    points <- quicksort_angle(points, low, p - 1, reference_point)
    points <- quicksort_angle(points, p + 1, high, reference_point)
  }
  return(points)
}

partition_angle<-function(points, low, high, reference_point){
  pivot <- points[high,]
  i <- low
  for(j in low:high){
    if(less_angle(points[j,], pivot, reference_point)){
      points<-swap(points, i, j)
      i<-i+1
    }
  }
  points<-swap(points, i, high)
  return(list('points'=points, 'p'=i))
}

less_angle<-function(check_point, pivot_point, reference_point){
  # m_check = (check_point$y - reference_point$y) / (check_point$x - reference_point$x)
  # m_pivot = (pivot_point$y - reference_point$y) / (pivot_point$x - reference_point$x)


  m_check = (reference_point$y - check_point$y) / (reference_point$x - check_point$x)
  m_pivot = (reference_point$y - pivot_point$y) / (reference_point$x - pivot_point$x)

  if((m_pivot * m_check) < 0){
    return(m_check > m_pivot)
  }else{
    return(m_check < m_pivot)
  }
}
```

And example of use (red is reference point and blue is sorted points)
[image]
And auxiliary function swap()

```
swap <- function(points, i, j) {
  temp <- points[i, ]
  points[i, ] <- points[j, ]
  points[j, ] <- temp
  return(points)
}
```

EDIT: example data (`dput(head(points, n = 10))`)

```
structure(list(x = c(407.377968561836, 320.925913405139, 806.236479437212, 
682.732644010102, 59.5188127646688, 195.601556062, 290.540224567521, 
449.757491987199, 760.845693320502, 544.514419493731), y = c(255.027047196869, 
63.905220010085, 922.746908532688, 956.717615367146, 244.059993790463, 
498.689062974649, 986.184075321769, 605.362085530069, 254.609465040965, 
711.789759260369)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

EDIT:solutions

My solution (`vertices <- grahamScanConvexHull(points); dput(head(vertices, n = 10))`)

```
structure(list(x = c(59.5188127646688, 320.925913405139), y = c(244.059993790463, 
63.905220010085)), row.names = c(10L, 1L), class = "data.frame")
```

Library function (`vertices <- points[chull(points),];dput(head(vertices, n = 10))`)

```
structure(list(x = c(760.845693320502, 320.925913405139, 59.5188127646688, 
290.540224567521, 682.732644010102, 806.236479437212), y = c(254.609465040965, 
63.905220010085, 244.059993790463, 986.184075321769, 956.717615367146, 
922.746908532688)), row.names = c(9L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Though you leave `quicksort_bottom_top()` and `quicksort_angle()` undefined here, rather than `quicksort_bottom_top <- function( `& `quicksort_angle <- function(` so perhaps a worked example with errors. I tried with data(meuse, package = 'sp') for x & y.

Comment: I have already edited the question with the whole code and a plot of a use case example. Thanks for helping

Comment: You're on your way to a great question here. Last suggestions. Write an order of functions use at the top (where results come out of one function and are consumed in the next - I'm for instance curious about right_turn inputs A, B, C), and provide the points your working with so everyone is looking at the same example data.

Comment: See `?chull`    xxxx

Comment: @Chris I have added comments to the main function to clarify the code flow. Also I called A, B, C cause they are vectors to diferent from points[i,] which is a dataframe row. The points are passed as data.frame but for some operations like counter clockwise chek I use vector because I am reutilizing code and do not need to rewrite them.Also I have added a screenshot of the last points used.

Comment: Finally, resist the urge to screenshot, `dput(head(my_x_y, n = 10))`, and compare your results (or errors) with @HongOoi suggested `chull`. Were this my code and the results were even close, I'd be very happy!

Comment: Added @chris. 
Anyway I have tried different set of randomly generated points and the results differ a lot, from doing the convex hull perfectly (or fail only one point) to this case where it returns only two points. So I think there is some small implementation detail that I am not taking into account. Thanks

Comment: Okay, so now, pick and publish 20+ points, run them thru `chull` and your code and note the differences to tighten up your code (or find where things run off track). And you'll accomplish the goal stated above in your question. Vale la pena!

Comment: Thank for all debugging with plots and more points I finally archive it. It was all a problem with poping elements from the "pseudoqueue"